# How to get total number of columns, column name, data type of a SQL in oracle

Tags: oracle, types, cursor

I want to know how to get total number of columns, individual column name and its corresponding data type in oracle. For example

```
SQL := 'SELECT UT.TABLESPACE_NAME, UT.TABLE_NAME, UT.STATUS, UT.NUM_ROWS, UT.LAST_ANALYZED, 
(select count(1) from USER_TAB_COLS utc where utc.table_name = UT.TABLE_NAME) column_count
from USER_TABLES ut;'
```

then procedure should be able to display following information:

```
Total columns = 6

Column-1: TABLESPACE_NAME
Data type: Varchar2

Column-2: TABLE_NAME
Data type: Varchar2

Column-3: STATUS
Data type: Varchar2

Column-4: NUM_ROWS
Data type: Numeric

Column-5: LAST_ANALYZED
Data type: DATE

Column-6: COLUMN_COUNT
Data type: Numeric
```

If we change the SQL then result should be changed accordingly.

Comment: What have you researched so far?   Most of that stuff can be found by querying the various metadata tables.   SELECT * FROM USER_TABLES for example.  Are you asking us to google that for you?

Comment: You are looking for `dbms_sql.describe_columns()`: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_sql.htm#i1026120

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pl/SQL- Get column names from a query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18020060/pl-sql-get-column-names-from-a-query)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT UT.TABLESPACE_NAME
, UT.TABLE_NAME
, UT.STATUS
, UT.NUM_ROWS
, UT.LAST_ANALYZED
, utc.column_name
, utc.data_type
, utc.data_length
, column_id ColumnNo
, max(utc.column_id) over (partition by ut.table_name) NoColumns
from USER_TABLES ut
inner join USER_TAB_COLS utc
on utc.table_name = ut.table_name
order by ut.tablespace_name
, ut.table_name
, utc.column_id
;
```