# PL/SQL extract SELECT statement column names from custom query

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, plsql

I have a custom query and I need to know how to extract colum names from this. I've already searched for any way to do it:

- Regex: I've build [this](https://regex101.com/r/OhmDwW/2) one to get more or less what I want but it won't work (I'm using Toad 12.6.0.53).

This is the code I have tried to test my regex:

```
DECLARE
  v_SQL VARCHAR2(32767 CHAR);
  v_Result VARCHAR2(32767 CHAR);
BEGIN 
  v_SQL := 'SELECT 
  ALIASBASE.CDCMPANY, 
  ALIASBASE.PAFCODCTR, 
  ALIASBASE.PAFDTSCAD, 
  NUMFLUSSO.NUMERO, 
  ALIASBASE.PAFDESC, 
  ALIASBASE.PAFTYPE, 
  ALIASBASE.PAFNATURE, 
  ALIASBASE.PAFRECEIV, 
  ALIASBASE.PAFCAUSAL, 
  ALIASBASE.PAFCODDNE, 
  ALIASBASE.PAFMATURITY
  FROM ALBSIAE';

  BEGIN
    SELECT 
      REGEXP_SUBSTR (v_SQL, '(?:\s*(?=\w+\.|.*as\s+|)(\*|\w+)(?=\s*(?=,|from)))',1, NULL,'i') REGEX_RESULT 
    INTO
      v_Result
    FROM DUAL;
  END;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('v_Result: ' || v_Result);
END;
```

But ant the end the v_Result is empty.

- Another way is to loop between my table columns,as I've seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18020060/pl-sql-get-column-names-from-a-query) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41137102/oracle-read-column-names-from-select-statement), but I think is not my case.

So, I want to know if is there any other way to do this, am I wrong with the regex? Is something wrong in it? Does Oracle have other regex syntax?

Comment: Try  `REGEXP_SUBSTR(v_SQL, '(\*|[[:alnum:]_]+)(\s*(,|from))', 1, 1, 'i', 1)`

Comment: It will work with regex only in a case of short simple queries. `WITH` clause or complex calculations in the `SELECT` clause will brake this solution. The better solution is to use `dbms_sql` package (http://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db121/ARPLS/d_sql.htm#ARPLS058).

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew. Could you please explain the syntax?

Comment: I guess you need to have a look at the other solution. A regex - even if fixed - will most probably cause further issues.

Comment: Example here: http://www.williamrobertson.net/documents/refcursor-to-csv.shtml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can parse the statement with *DBMS_SQL.parse* and get the columns with  *DBMS_SQL.describe_columns*:

```
DECLARE
  v_SQL VARCHAR2(32767 CHAR);
  v_Result VARCHAR2(32767 CHAR) := '';
  l_cursor        PLS_INTEGER;
  l_col_cnt       PLS_INTEGER;
  i               PLS_INTEGER;
  l_desc_tab      DBMS_SQL.desc_tab;
BEGIN 
  v_SQL := q'[SELECT 1 as "MY_NUMBER", 'z' as "MY_CHAR" from dual]';
  l_cursor := DBMS_SQL.open_cursor;
  DBMS_SQL.parse(l_cursor, v_SQL, DBMS_SQL.native);
  DBMS_SQL.describe_columns(l_cursor, l_col_cnt, l_desc_tab);

  FOR i IN 1 .. l_col_cnt LOOP
    v_Result := v_Result ||' ' || l_desc_tab(i).col_name;
  END LOOP;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('v_Result: ' || v_Result);

END;
/
```