# Get column names of the result of a query Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need a query that will get the column names of the result of another query. The other query can be anything - I can't make any assumptions about it but it will typically be some `SELECT` statement.

For example, if I have this table `Members`

```
Id | Name | Age
---|------|----
1  | John | 25
2  | Amir | 13
```

And this `SELECT` statement
`SELECT Name, Age FROM Members`

Then the result of the query I'm trying to write would be

```
Name
Age
```

In SQL Server, there is a function - `sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set` - that does this but I can't find an equivalent in Oracle.

I tried to use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32688011) but I can't use `CREATE TYPE` statements because of permissions issues and I probably can't use `CREATE FUNCTION` statements for the same reason.

Comment: This will be hard, if you don't have permission to do certain things. You may tell your bosses that you can't solve the problem without those permissions - either they grant them to you (even on a temporary basis) or they assign the task to someone else who does have the permissions. For example: columns (and column names) may be created in a PIVOT clause, or in a MATCH_RECOGNIZE clause, etc. The query may be SELECT * FROM ... and the column names come from PIVOT or MATCH_RECOGNIZE or a whole world of other things.

Comment: The only way I know to do it is to use dynamic sql with DBMS_SQL, and it is a royal pain

Comment: A general solution is to create a view from your select statement - then you can inspect the view easily (in particular, to see what column names it has); but to do this, you need to be able to create a view. If you can't create views, then you can't use this approach, even though it is perhaps the simplest.

Comment: @mathguy could you give me an example of what that would look like?

Comment: If `JDBC` is an option you may use resultSet.[getMetaData](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getMetaData())

Comment: Since 12c you may use `with function` to build column list as a single `varchar2/clob` with the code in the linked answer, and then use, for example, `xmltable` to turn it into rowset. This doesn't require `create` privileges

Comment: This is something that SQL, the querying language, isn't made for. Well, astenix has mentioned a way to get the column names from a query, still. Commonly, however, this is not a task for SQL. But the DBMS does this in its conversation with your app. When your app sends a query string like this `SELECT Name, Age FROM Members` or this `SELECT * FROM Members` to the DBMS, the DBMS will not only return an anonimous result table, but also include the column names.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a query like this:

```
select *
from   (select deptno, job, sal from scott.emp)
pivot  (avg(sal) as avg_sal for job in 
           ('ANALYST' as analyst, 'CLERK' as clerk, 'SALESMAN' as salesman)
       )
order by deptno
;
```

This produces the result:

```
    DEPTNO ANALYST_AVG_SAL CLERK_AVG_SAL SALESMAN_AVG_SAL
---------- --------------- ------------- ----------------
        10                          1300                 
        20            3000           950                 
        30                           950             1400
```

Notice the column names (like `ANALYST_AVG_SAL`) - they don't appear exactly in that form **anywhere** in the query! They are made up from two separate pieces, put together with an underscore.

Now, if you were allowed to create views (note that this does not create any data in your database - it just saves the text of a query), you could do this:

Create the view (just add the first line of code to what we already had):

```
create view q201028_vw as
select *
from   (select deptno, job, sal from scott.emp)
pivot  (avg(sal) as avg_sal for job in 
            ('ANALYST' as analyst, 'CLERK' as clerk, 'SALESMAN' as salesman)
       )
order by deptno
;
```

(Here I assumed you have some way to identify the query, an id like `Q201028`, and used that in the view name. That is not important, unless you need to do this often and for a large number of queries at the same time.)

Then you can find the column names (and also their order, and - if needed - their data type, etc.) by querying `*_TAB_COLUMNS`. For example:

```
select column_id, column_name
from   user_tab_columns
where  table_name = 'Q201028_VW'
order  by column_id
;

 COLUMN_ID COLUMN_NAME         
---------- --------------------
         1 DEPTNO              
         2 ANALYST_AVG_SAL     
         3 CLERK_AVG_SAL       
         4 SALESMAN_AVG_SAL
```

Now you can drop the view if you don't need it for anything else.

As an aside: The "usual" way to "save" queries in the database, in Oracle, is to create views. If they already exist as such in your DB, then all you need is the last step I showed you. Otherwise, were is the "other query" (for which you need to find the columns) coming from in the first place?

Comment: Well explained, thank you! Hopefully I can get permission to create views.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the dbms_sql package and the following code example should show you how to start:

```
DECLARE
    cursorID            INTEGER;
    status              INTEGER;
    colCount            INTEGER;
    rowCount            INTEGER;
  description       dbms_sql.desc_tab;
    colType             INTEGER;
    stringValue     VARCHAR2(32676);
    sqlCmd              VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
    -- open cursor
    cursorID := dbms_sql.open_cursor;

    -- parse statement
    dbms_sql.parse(cursorID, 'select * from user_tables', dbms_sql.native);

    -- describe columns
    dbms_sql.describe_columns(cursorID, colCount, description);

    -- cursor close
    dbms_sql.close_cursor(cursorID);

    -- open cursor
    cursorID := dbms_sql.open_cursor;

    -- assemble a new select only using up to 5 the "text" columns
    FOR i IN 1 .. description.COUNT LOOP
        IF (i > 5) THEN
            EXIT;
        END IF;
        IF (description(i).col_type IN (1, 112)) THEN
            IF (sqlCmd IS NOT NULL) THEN
                 sqlCmd := sqlCmd || ', ';
            END IF;
            sqlCmd := sqlCmd || description(i).col_name;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
    sqlCmd := 'SELECT ' || sqlCmd || ' FROM user_tables';
    dbms_output.put_line(sqlCmd);

    -- parse statement
    dbms_sql.parse(cursorID, sqlCmd, dbms_sql.native);

    -- describe columns
    dbms_sql.describe_columns(cursorID, colCount, description);

    -- define columns
    FOR i IN 1 .. description.COUNT LOOP
        dbms_sql.define_column(cursorID, i, stringValue, 4000);
    END LOOP;

    -- execute
    status := dbms_sql.execute(cursorID);

    -- fetch up to 5 rows
    rowCount := 0;
    WHILE (dbms_sql.fetch_rows(cursorID) > 0) LOOP
        rowCount := rowCount + 1;
        IF (rowCount > 5) THEN
            EXIT;
        END IF;
        dbms_output.put_line('row # ' || rowCount);
        FOR i IN 1 .. description.COUNT LOOP
            dbms_sql.column_value(cursorID, i, stringValue);
            dbms_output.put_line('column "' || description(i).col_name || '" = "' || stringValue || '"');
        END LOOP;
    END LOOP;

    -- cursor close
    dbms_sql.close_cursor(cursorID);
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

As astentx suggested, you can use a common table expression function to package the PL/SQL code into a SQL statement. This solution is just a single SQL statement, and requires no non-default privileges and does not create any permanent objects.

(The only downside is that not all SQL tools understand these kinds of WITH clauses, and they may throw an error expecting a different statement terminator.)

```
SQL> create table members(id number, name varchar2(100), age number);

Table created.

SQL> with function get_result_column_names(p_sql varchar2) return sys.odcivarchar2list is
  2      v_cursor_id integer;
  3      v_col_cnt integer;
  4      v_columns dbms_sql.desc_tab;
  5  v_column_names sys.odcivarchar2list := sys.odcivarchar2list();
  6  begin
  7      v_cursor_id := dbms_sql.open_cursor;
  8      dbms_sql.parse(v_cursor_id, p_sql, dbms_sql.native);
  9      dbms_sql.describe_columns(v_cursor_id, v_col_cnt, v_columns);
 10
 11      for i in 1 .. v_columns.count loop
 12  v_column_names.extend;
 13  v_column_names(v_column_names.count) := v_columns(i).col_name;
 14      end loop;
 15
 16      dbms_sql.close_cursor(v_cursor_id);
 17
 18  return v_column_names;
 19  exception when others then
 20      dbms_sql.close_cursor(v_cursor_id);
 21      raise;
 22  end;
 23  select *
 24  from table(get_result_column_names(q'[select name, age from members]'));
 25  /

COLUMN_VALUE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
NAME
AGE
```